# Inconsistence of text on bonsaijs

Tags: bonsaijs

I'm just getting started with BonsaiJS and I've found some odd behaviour with how Text gets displayed. As the following pic shows, on Chrome(25), Firefox(19) and IE(9) the text example on the site is only shown correctly on chrome, while the same example on orbit appears to be correct in all 3 browsers, except the white space left at the top varies for some reason..

[image: inconsistent text display]

Any clue as to why this may be happening and how could I fix it?

PS: I've lowered the textStrokeWidth because I couldn't stand the text being shown in all yellow '^^

Answer (score 0):

I assume this issue has been fixed in version 0.4.3.

- Latest 0.4 build: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bonsai/0.4/bonsai.min.js
- According ticket: https://github.com/uxebu/bonsai/issues/166

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry that I never saw your reply. I've just tested it and it stil happens.

Comment: Yep. you're right. It is supposed to be fixed in Firefox. It's still an issue in IE. IE just ignores vertical alignment :( I recommend following the github ticket for further infos.